# requirejs firing callbacks before dependencies are loaded - sometimes

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a requirejs app that is not loading consistently. Typically it works as long as I'm on a cached set of content but that's not a big surprise. However clearing cache almost always causes scripts to not be present.

I'm not including dependencies outside of my application - everything is included via define() dependency injection.

My main.js file contains the following, which is launched using data-main per requirejs standards:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "script/module",
    paths: {
        "signals": "vendor/signals"
    }
});

require(["mainController"], function(){
    console.log("Full dependency tree load complete");
});
```

My main controller contains the following:

```
define(
    ["vendor/preloadjs", "router"],
    function (createjs, router) {
        //At this point all controllers are loaded and ready to go
        console.log("main controller"); //This successfully fires every time
        return {};
    }
);
```

The problem lies in router.js:

```
define(
    ["vendor/crossroads", "vendor/hasher"],
    function(xr, h) {
        console.log(xr, h);
        return {};
    }
);
```

The log in this file will *usually* output the correct object for crossroads (xr in this case), and *sometimes* will output the correct object for hasher (h). However 3 or 4 times out of ten (when refreshing with a cache) and 10 times out of 10 when refreshing without cached content, it breaks. And it doesn't break consistently. Sometimes crossroads will be undefined, sometimes hasher will be the following object:

```
{
    noConflict: ()
    parse: parse()
    runInContext: a(b, d)
    stringify: stringify()
    __proto__: Object
}
```

And sometimes signals.js (a dependency defined for both hasher and crossroads, which is defined in the paths config in the main js file) fails to load and I get other errors such as a.Signal is not defined.

What I'm seeing here is that my callbacks are firing before my dependencies have loaded. All three of these dependencies are amd/require enabled, and they work "some" of the time. Isn't the entire point of require.js to NOT fire callbacks before the dependency tree is loaded? What am I missing?

Thanks!!!

Comment: That object you show in your question looks like you are getting a reference to the [JSON 3](https://github.com/bestiejs/json3) library. Anyhow, do you call `require` anywhere outside of your `main` module or the modules that it loads.

Comment: I'm working on a large framework. We have jQuery as well as Greensock (TweenMax) installed. I know Greensock and jQuery both call define, but not require to my knowledge. Is that going to cause issues if I'm not referencing those things though?

Comment: I dont even understand. I get a completely different result every time I refresh the page. This is frustrating.

Comment: jQuery does not call `require`. It does not depend on anything. A very common cause of intermittent issues is putting the configuration of RequireJS in `main`, putting `data-main="main"` but having some piece of code *outside* main call `require` because `data-main` causes the main module to load *asynchronously* this means that the config is also loaded asynchronously and sometimes this external `require` executes after the configuration has loaded, sometimes not. However, it does not seem to be your case. I strongly advise producing a [mcve] for your question, otherwise we'll be guessing.

Comment: Actually you might be right. Those aren't the only additional scripts. We have lots of libraries but those were two that I know use AMD. Let me dig through and see.
That said, is there a way to sandbox these things? I saw something about config contexts but I'm not sure that will help or not (tried it, didn't work). I'll get back about the other stuff... Thanks, you're being quite helpful.